# Reading text from anywhere on mobile screen with accessibility service in android without click event

Tags: android, android-studio, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I am trying to read text from anywhere on mobile screen with accessibility service. Well, I've tried many tutorials and solutions but what I want is a bit different. I have a floating button on screen like chathead, I want to read the text from the specific area bellow the floating button. An application **UDictionary** is already doing it and i have attached a short clip of it. I'm successfully getting text by clicking on the text but the Question is:

How to get text by dragging the floating button over text and without click ?

**Video clip:**

[image]

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: hi @CarlosArturoAlaniz I am sorry for late response, still I am unable to solve this. If you have any clue, please do share so it help everyone.